# Forecasting by autoregressions of invertible linear transform of variables

Tags: regression, forecasting, data-transformation, autoregressive

Suppose I have two variables and two alternative variables, where the latter are an invertible linear transform of the former. Suppose further, that I estimate both the new and the original variables as a pure autoregression on one or more lags (and a constant), the same number of lags for the original and the alternative variables.

If I do forecasts with both sets of variables, and then apply the inverse transform on the forecasts from the alternative variables, will they be necessarily the same, except for rounding error?

If not, is there anything I can derive a priori about the quality of the two forecasts from complete information about the original data and the transform? In other words, is it ever the case that I can improve the quality of my forecasts (by autoregression) by applying a linear transform?

This question is motivated by a data set that contains two similarly variable and similarly trended variables, and a linear combination that, rather surprisingly, puts virtually all of the trend in one variable and virtually all of the variability in the other.